# Display and Sort dates in a DataGridView bound to SQLite

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite, datetime, datagridview

I'm having a problem getting dates to either display or sort correctly in my DataGridView. The dgv.DataSource is bound to a DataTable which is populated with data from an SQLite database. Since SQLite doesn't have a "datetime" column type, I'm stuck storing the dates as strings (or integers).

So, either I store the date in a format that is sortable (such as SQLite's recommended "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS" format) and have it be not (easily) readable for the user, or I store it in a more human readable format ("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm AM/PM") and have it not sortable.

Obviously neither option is good.

Does anyone know how to store a date in a sortable format while also displaying it in a datagridview in a readable format?

WATYF

Answer (score 1):

Save the dates in milliseconds format and convert it while showing on the grid, they are sortable.

Comment: One of the formats I've tried storing it in includes the milliseconds, which makes it sortable. The problem is displaying it to the user in a readable format when I store it that way. How would I "convert it while showing on the grid"?

Comment: DateTime date = new DateTime(long.Parse(ticks));date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");

Comment: Where would I use that?